# Click any where on a webpage

Tags: selenium

i  need to perform  click(From Mouse)  anywhere  on the webpage . clicking any where on the web page a scrubber bar opens or closes at the bottom of the webpage.

Please tell me how to perform click anywhere on the WebPage using Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Perform mouse movement using Robot class.
Use below method to perform cursor move:

```
 robot.mouseMove(x,y);
```

Here x,y represents the position on the webpage.

example for mouse movement and click actions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.mouseMove(50,50);

actions.click().build().perform();

robot.mouseMove(200,70);

actions.click().build().perform();
```

Comment: I need to click on any where  of the page randomly.

Comment: it will click on the webpage wherever the cursor present.

Comment: Hi Saritha  Thanks for reply. Could you please tell me the default dimension of the top left corner of the page.

Comment: (0,0) is the dimension value of browser's top left corner.

Comment: I just modified the code . But its not working. I  added your code i my script.,    Can  you please tell me why two times the robot.mousemove() required.

Comment: Saritha Could you please also let me know  how to determine the present location of the cursor while running the script. Saritha there is no keyboard action in my application.

Comment: I have used robot.mousemove() for times to get clarity for you. You can use only once with required dimension values i.e., where you want to perform mouse click.

Comment: why do you want current cursor position?? And which action you want to perform with keyboard?

Comment: On execution My script needs to perform a click on the web page so that I can handle the taskbar which appears or disappear when the mouse is clicked

Comment: yah..you can click anywhere on the webpage, move mouse to a position using Robot.moveMouse(x,y); and click over there using actions.click().

Answer (score 1):

One way I have done this is to click on the body element.  It works for me when using the Material Design's md-select object.

```
$('body').click();
```