# How to run an Eclipse Maven program to launch chrome browser using .bat(batch)?

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, command

I create a cmd file using

```
java -cp classpackage.classname
```

and save it as a cmd file.
After I create a batch file and write it in the cmd file path.
And then click on the batch file so I get the error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class artifactiidpack.articlassss
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Comment: Export your main class to runnable jar file. You can run the jar file directly or from bat file using `java -cp FOO.jar packagename.classname`.

Comment: Thank you sir.. and one more question ....can we click setting button of browser using selenium java

Comment: You can simulate click anywhere on the screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066403/click-any-where-on-a-webpage. But you need to know exact position, so somehow to count with different screen size and resolution.